# How to join 3 column based on one coumn

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I would like to compare the first column of three files. if matched, i would like to  print the output as 4th column from file2 and 5th column from 2nd column of fil3. If no matches 0 will be added into the 4th and 5th column of the output.

```
  file1.txt
      123,apple,goodquality
        456,orange,mediumquality
        678,grape,lowquality
    786,kiwi,goodquality

file2.txt
123,55
678,2

file3.txt
456,10

output.txt
123,apple,goodquality,55,0
456,orange,mediumquality,0,10
678,grape,lowquality,2,0
```

I was using join command it works well if the column1 value is availble in all 3 files.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join the first 2 files, and then join that output with the 3rd file. You'll need several extra options for join to do an outer join, with 0 as the default field value. Assuming your files are already sorted *lexicographically* by the first field, then:

```
join -t , -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o 0,1.2,2.1     file1.txt file2.txt | 
join -t , -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.1 -         file3.txt
```

outputs

```
123,apple,123,0
456,orange,0,456
678,grape,678,0
786,kiwi,0,0
```

And if you want to exclude the last line for having 2 zero values, then

```
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o 0,1.2,2.1     file1.txt file2.txt |
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.1 -         file3.txt |
sed '/,0,0$/d'
```

Comment: I never used these parameters in join command, can you please explain the same. Or please share links to explore. Thanks @glenn

Comment: But in the output 3rd column is missed

Comment: Ah very true. Can you spot where I made my mistake?  Hint it's in one of the options in each join command